# Expose IList<T> or ReadOnlyCollection<T> for Read-Only Property?

Tags: .net, mono, readonly-collection

I realize that since .NET 4.5 that the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` class implements the new interface `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` but I am constrained to an older version of the library which doesn't have this.

I would like to know which of the better is considered to be best practice:

```
public sealed class OptionA {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a read-only list of numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> SomeNumbers {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(_someNumbers); }
    }

    ...

}

public sealed class OptionB {

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a read-only list of numbers.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<int> SomeNumbers {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(_someNumbers); }
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Best practice under what circumstances? It depends on which one you want.

Comment: There isn't much point in suggesting to the client programmer that the Add() method is going to work.

Comment: @BartoszKP Since `IList<T>` provides random access and `IEnumerable<T>` does not.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree, that is certainly a nice trait that the mutable methods are hidden.

Comment: @AntP Where possible I like to expose interfaces rather than a concrete implementation. In the case of this wrapper class I was unsure as to how people typically expose the read-only collections with it in their libraries.

Comment: @BartoszKP Thanks! I wasn't aware of that implementation detail in Linq. That is great to know. Post this as the answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it will make your code as loosely coupled as possible in this case. It also provides random access with the [`ElementAt<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method, which will work with *O(1)* complexity if the actual type implements [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5y536ey6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> If the type of source implements `IList<T>`, that implementation is used to obtain the element at the specified index. Otherwise, this method obtains the specified element.

Exposing `IList<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` could be useful if you really wanted to stress the fact that random access with constant-time complexity is available. Deciding which one really depends on a particular scenario.